# Mongodb Angular filters for creating a sidebar menu

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, search, filter

I have imported a json file to my mongodb database. Its about 1.000.000 records, it was really fast as i wanted and everything go pretty well. Im trying to create a sidebar menu with filters in order to create a better UX for the visitor. I want to filter my documents by color, size ect...

every documents (product) has this format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5862f2eceb9c671910ce6b37"),
    "product_name" : "Black heels D&G n15",
    "category" : "Woman - Shoes - heels",
    "color" : "black - white - yellow",
    "size" : "onesize - 40 - 41 - 42",
    "tracking_url" : "http://go.linkwi.se/z/11757-0/CD19722/?lnkurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.classico.gr%2Fproductdetails.aspx%3Fcode%3DJA.00194%26c%3DGRE",
    "image_url" : "https://www.domain.com/photos/verybig/JA.194-GRE1.JPG"
```

Im new in angular and mongodb, i have search a lot in the internet and still couldnt find a way to create what i want. any ideas or advices? thanks :)